# How to change redirect uri for new SharePoint AddIn version without breaking existing clients, when publishing to Office Store?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-store

I need to change redirect url in new version of AddIn, that is already published in Office Store. The only way I found is through creating new client ids in Seller Dashboard. But when i try to change client ids for new version of App, the notification appears saying that this will break  existing clients. Is there any way to add new redirect url and to avoid this breaking change for existing clients?

[image]